# Disconnecting all ethernet ports from router when one of them gets disconnected

Tags: router

I have a router with 4 connections. And what I want to do is to disconnect all of them when one of them gets disconnected (especially mine, which is in port 2.) Is this possible?

Using a D-LINK router, [this](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-600-wireless-n-150-home-router) model.

Comment: Unless this is a feature of the router, then no.

Comment: I'm curious... why?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It is a bit silly but I am staying in my parents house for a while, and my little brother keeps disconnecting my port when he gets a bit of lag (we are using satellite internet, so it is pretty slow), and I usually use Skype for work-related things and it is pretty annoying, as he does this frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard firmware I wouldn't say so. But you could install eventually the [OpenWrt firmware](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-600) in which case that could be possibile. You could just do a script monitoring the specific switch ports (or evenually do it IP based to make it simpler) and then executing something afterwards (for example disable certain ports with ethtool or with a iptables rule).

Not something immediate to do but for sure feasible.